# Detect path of font on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, fonts

I know name of my font, how to detect path from command line ?

I read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/760627/how-to-list-installed-font-families), but solution show only fonts on the system without path.

Comment: Installed fonts are in `C:\Windows\Fonts`.

Comment: **C:\Windows\Fonts**  is default directory, but I found fonts also to **C:\Users\omen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 10 1803 has introduced
[fonts in the Microsoft Store](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2018/01/24/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17083-for-pc/).
This required to allow a font to be installed for a specific user rather
than system-wide. That’s why no admin action is needed when fonts
acquired from the Store are installed.

This change meant that there now exist two repositories for fonts:

1. **Fonts for all users**, residing in folder
   `C:\Windows\Fonts` and listed in the registry at key
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`.
2. **Fonts for the current user**, residing in folder
   `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`
   and listed in the registry at key
   `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`.

To list all fonts, you will need to query both registry keys that
I listed above. For each font under one of the two registry keys,
you will then know its folder.

Comment: Fonts for the current user with reg query return full path, the *problem* is with Fonts for all users return only name of font, and  "C:\" is standard for all PC or potentialy is possible custom with another letter ?

Comment: For all users, you will need to append the path yourself. We have to manage with Microsoft's inconsistencies.